# Setup /storage and /bootstrap/cache permissions on homestead for Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, vagrant, file-permissions, laravel-5.8, homestead

I use homestead and I have recently updated my application to Laravel 5.8.
Since then, I am getting permission errors whenever I try to login/logout.

The errors I'm getting are like the following:

```
UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/home/vagrant/Code/myapp/storage/logs/laravel-2022-04-11.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Here's an `ll` of my /storage/logs folder (without ssh into homestead):

```
drwxrwsrwx 2 username www-data   4096 Apr 12 01:32 ./
drwxrwsrwx 5 username www-data   4096 Oct 27  2020 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username www-data  11700 Nov 28 21:25 laravel-2021-11-28.log*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username www-data   5850 Feb  9 21:13 laravel-2022-02-09.log*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username www-data 203687 Feb 13 22:58 laravel-2022-02-13.log*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username www-data  19324 Apr 12 01:39 laravel-2022-04-11.log*
```

And here's an `ll` of my /storage/logs folder (with ssh into homestead):

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   4096 Apr 11 22:32 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   4096 Oct 27  2020 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  11700 Nov 28 19:25 laravel-2021-11-28.log*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   5850 Feb  9 19:13 laravel-2022-02-09.log*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 203687 Feb 13 20:58 laravel-2022-02-13.log*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  19324 Apr 11 22:39 laravel-2022-04-11.log*
```

Notice that the users/groups are different.
Do not pay so much attention to the current permissions - nothing changes if I put the default permissions.

Now, let's say I try to login.
What will happen is that I will get the error I said in the beginning and the permissions for the last log file (the daily file for the current day) will change to this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  95308 Apr 11 22:48 laravel-2022-04-11.log
```

If I run:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
```

then the permission of the file returns to:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  95308 Apr 11 22:48 laravel-2022-04-11.log*
```

and when I refresh the page, the login has worked.

Obviously, the `www-data` user is trying to write something in the log file while trying to login and it fails because the permissions are not 777 (and they shouldn't be).

In my `config/logging.php` file I can see the following:

```
     'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 14,
            'permission' => 0664,
        ],
```

Notice the `'permission' => 0664` part. This is why the permissions of the file change when I try to login.
If I change this to `0777`, it works but I get a permissions error in the /storage/framework/sessions directory.
Also, this should remain 0664 due to security considerations.

I have tried every answer on SO on this problem but nothing has worked.

My production server works fine (thankfully).

Any ideas??

Comment: If your webserver creates the log file (start by just deleting all the log files) then it will be owned by www-data.  If you run an artisan command that needs to write to log then the log file will be created by, and owned by vagrant.  
Since your permissions are 664, you should make sure vagrant and www-data are in the same group so they can write to each others files.

Comment: @Snapey can you please create a detailed answer on how to do what you suggest? When I delete all the log files and then try to login, I get the error: The stream or file "/home/vagrant/Code/foodonsale/storage/logs/laravel-2022-04-11.log" could not be opened in append mode: chmod(): No such file or directory. If I create the file using `touch`, I get the same error. I have added `www-data` user to `vagrant` group and vice-versa but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

It took me days to solve this, so here's what worked for me.

This is a Vagrant/Homestead issue.
When Homestead boots up, the correct permissions/owners should already be set; there is no way to change them later (neither from within -ssh- nor outside homestead).

According to [Vagrant's DOC](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage), we can use the Vagrantfile to set different permissions to certain directories.
What worked for me was to include the following  in my Vagrantfile:

```
    config.vm.synced_folder "/home/username/Code/myapp/", "/home/vagrant/Code/myapp", :owner => "www-data", :group => "www-data"
```

After adding this config, my project folders/files are owned by `www-data` in Homestead.

**Some important notes:**

1. The above config needs to go inside the `Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|` section of the Vagrantfile.
2. The first path (`/home/username/Code/myapp/`) is the path to your project directory on your host machine (ie. your pc) and the second path (`/home/vagrant/Code/myapp`) is the path inside your VM/Vagrant/Homestead environment.
3. Remember to provision after you make any changes.
4. You can verify that Homestead is using your changes by checking the output when you run `homestead up --provision`. Mine looks something like this:

```
==> homestead-7: Mounting shared folders...
    homestead-7: /vagrant => /home/username/Homestead
    homestead-7: /home/vagrant/Code => /home/username/Code
    homestead-7: /home/vagrant/Code/myapp => /home/username/Code/myapp
```

The last line is the one we added.
This line `homestead-7: /home/vagrant/Code => /home/username/Code` is the default mapping which is configured on your `Homestead.yaml` file:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

so, in my case, the `Code` directory has the default permissions and the `Code/myapp` directory has `www-data` as an owner.
You can set the permissions in as many directories as you want.